# Jsoup select and iterate all elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I will connect to a url through jsoup and get all the contents of it but the thing is if I select like,

```
doc.select("body")
```

its returning a single element but I want to get all the elements in the page and iterate them one by one for example,

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p>Hello All</p>
<a href="test.html">Second Page</a>
<div>Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I select using body I am getting the result in a single line like,

```
Test Hello All Second Page Test
```

Instead I want to select all elements and iterate one by one and produce the results like,

```
Test
Hello All
Second Page
Test
```

Will that be possible using jsoup?

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can select all elements of the document using `*` selector and then get text of each individually using `Element#ownText()`.

```
Elements elements = document.body().select("*");

for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.ownText());
}
```

Comment: No this is also producing the same output, any idea?

Comment: Then it are no direct children of the body as you demonstrated in your question. I'll update the answer.

Comment: you should use document.getAllElements() instead that selector. see https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getAllElements--

Comment: I'm getting the error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable"

Answer (score 5):

To get all of the elements within the body of the document using jsoup library.

`doc.body().children().select("*");`

To get just the first level of elements in the documents body elements.

`doc.body().children();`

Comment: That is an important distinction that is not immediately obvious from the other answers. Thanks. To get the first level elements of the document body and *their* children (second example), as opposed to a flat list of all the elements within the body tag (first example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath or any library which contain XPath

the expression is `//text()`

Test the expression with your xml [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm)

Comment: would you expand on how `xpath` interacts with `jsoup`?