# Jsoup wiki scraper how do I get table of contents box

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am having trouble scraping the table of contents on wiki. I am making a simple web scraper for a personal project and I can't figure out how to scrape this data.

Here is my attempt at scraping the table of contents from any given wiki page

```
 String contentOver = doc.select("#toclimit-3 > li").first().text();
```

HERE IS THE CODE FROM THE PAGE I want to scrape, how do I get just the word "Chronology"?:

```
    <ul> 
    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Chronology"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Chronology</span></a></li>
```

Comment: doc.select(".toctext").first().text(); //<<<THIS WORKS thanks alecxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get it by the class name:

```
 Element li = doc.select("#toclimit-3 > li").first();
 String result = li.select(".toctext").first().text();
```

Comment: @StreamingBits could you try just this `doc.select(".toctext").first().text();`?

Comment: @StreamingBits Omit the `first().text()` and take an approach similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039950/771848.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be selecting all the source code? I just want to select all those elements?

Comment: @StreamingBits yup, replace "*" with ".toctext".