# How to Count total Html Tags using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

Hello guys how can I count the total number of html tags without counting them one by one? For example:

**I don't** **want** something like this:

```
   int count=0;
   count=doc.getElementsByTag("img").size()+doc.getElementsByTag("div").size()+doc.getElementsByTag("a").size()+doc.getElementsByTag("p").size();

System.out.println("Scripts inside HTML " + count);
```

Is there a way to count all these tags into one command in **Jsoup**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup select and iterate all elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036332)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to find this. You can use `document.select("*");` or `org.jsoup.select.Collector` or `document.getAllElements()` to get all the elements. All returns a list of elements. The size of that list gives the number of tags. Also you can iterate through the elements and get the tag name. Or atit to a set to find the distinct names. The below program list all these.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Collector;
import org.jsoup.select.Evaluator;


public class CountTags {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("Number of tags by getAllElements() method =" + document.getAllElements().size());
            System.out.println("Number of tags by Collector.collect() method =" + Collector.collect(new Evaluator.AllElements(), document).size());
            System.out.println("Number of tags by select(\"*\") method =" + document.select("*").size());
            for(Element e : document.getAllElements()){
                tags.add(e.tagName().toLowerCase());
            }
            System.out.println("The tags = " + tags);
            System.out.println("Distinct tags = " + new HashSet<String>(tags));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```