# get inner tags from HTML

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm new to JSoup so a help would be great. In this [official tutorial](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html), we could learn that code below gets inner tag as String:

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

But what if the HTML string is extremely long and therefore contains a lot of  tags? Is there a limitation in this case? How could I make an array or arraylist of String containing all inner tags of "a"

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is similar to a DOM parser. It paser the entire html to a tree structure. So the size that it could parse depends on the java heap size you configured.

And as for getting a tag there are several ways. Easiest one would be `document.select()` method. Just like Masud's answer.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parser(html);
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Element e : document.select("a")){
    tags.add(e.tagName());
}
System.out.println("The tags = " + tags);

//If you want it as array
String[] tagsArray = tags.toArray(new String[tags.size()]);
```

You can refer to this answer for more option [How to Count total Html Tags using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971318/how-to-count-total-html-tags-using-jsoup/)

Comment: since e.tagName() retrieve the name of the tag which is always "a", I changed it to e.html() to get the inner tag and now it seems to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How could I make an array or arraylist of String containing all inner
>   tags of "a"

You can return `Elements` from doc. Here `Elements` is an array containing all `<a>` tag.

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
   Elements allAnchorTags = doc.select("a");

   System.out.println(allAnchorTags); // It will print all tag string.
```

Comment: then how do I convert the element to array or list of string?

Comment: assuming that each value of the String[] is the content of each "a" tag