# JSoup - Parse HTML tag by tag

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm actually developping a text parser in Java and I was asked to enhance it by parsing HTML with it. 
The parser's purpose is to divide the file parsed into 3 other files, one with all the words contained in the file, one with all sentences and the other with all questions.

The *.txt part works perfectly, but I got a problem when parsing HTML.

I create a temporary file with *.txt extension and pass it in my text parser, but if I pass an URL with HTML file linked which is formed like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        ... some HTML here ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="some_menu">
            <li class="some_menu_item">n1</li>
            <li class="some_menu_item">n2</li>
            <li class="some_menu_item">n2</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            This is a question ?
            This is a sentence .
            ... some other text ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the question file will be filled with: `n1 n2 n3 This is a question`

So, I just was wondering, is there a way to parse with JSoup tags by tags so I can add a line feed each time a block is closed?

If you need some new informations, don't bother to ask!

**Edit:** I should have 3 output files, which are, for this example:

1. One with all the words

   ```
   n1
   n2
   n3
   This
   is
   a
   question
   sentence
   ... some other words ...
   ```
2. One with all the sentences

   ```
   This is a sentence
   ```
3. One with all the questions

   ```
   This is a question
   ```

TimmyM

Comment: Yes you can iterate through the tags one by one and get the text separately. However, I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Can you give an example of what you want out of this HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the text in an html body, you can use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements body = doc.select("body");
String allText = body[0].text();
```

You can then split the text to get each word separate.
To get the text in the div tag, you can use:

```
Elements div = doc.select("div");
String divText = div[0].text();
```

You can then split the divText to get each sentence.

Notice that the return type of the select query is actually a list of Element i.e., Elements. That's because there can be more than one elements matching you `select` query. In this case, since there is only one element for each case we access it by accessing the index 0 of the returned array.

Edit: In order to iterate through all elements check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036332/jsoup-select-and-iterate-all-elements). Basically

```
Elements elements = doc.body().select("*");

for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Though there might be elements with no texts so you can put a check on that.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing right now, but the real purpose here is to add on my generated file a `\n`each time I got a closing tag. doing so will permit my parser to separate menus' text from actual text for example. So I was wondering if there's not a generic way, so I could iterate in each tags on the page

Comment: Check my edit that points to another answer that might help you in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Gonna check that! Cheers

Answer (score -2):

There are quite a lot HTML parser available in market like

1. HTMLUnit
2. HTMLCleaner
3. Jericho
4. JSoup

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers

Thanks,
Vineet

Comment: The question was not about available parsers. It's about how to do it in Jsoup. This answer is completely unrelated.

Comment: unrelated answer