# Check if two html tags contain same attributes in different order using Java

Tags: java, html, string, algorithm, data-structures

I have a task a check if two html tags are of same meaning. like the two below: Although the attribute themselves appear in different order, they are expressed as the same meaning, so they should be classified as the same.

Another tricky thing is note that the attributes under `style attribute` are in the same situation : different order but same meaning.

```
<div class="d1" style="color:#0000FF; width:200px">
<div style="width:200px; color:#0000FF" class="d1">
```

The method I can think of is for each one push every attribute of them into an array and sort it, and check if the arrays are the same, but how can I deal with those "nested" attribute. I just cannot come up with a workable solution to this.

How can I do this? Is there any special data structures and algorithms I can use to tackle this? Is there any libraries I can use?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and it seems like no research has been done.

Comment: Parse the attributes, put them in `Set` objects and compare with `equals()`.

Comment: You might want to go for a html parser see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058229/jsoup-parse-html-tag-by-tag) if you haven't allready.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the attributes in an array seems like the right call. As for the "nested" attributes try using the split string method setting ';' as the delimiter.

Something like:

```
String css = "color:#0000FF; width:200px";
String[] elems = css.split(";");
for(String elem: elems){
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

would yield the output:

```
color:#0000FF
width:200px
```

Once you had the css in its own array you could compare it with the same algorithm that sorts and compares the rest of the elements.