# Get HTML tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to get Amazon item data from a URL and need to iterate through `item` tags in the document, but I cannot find the tag.

An example URL can be found [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_4?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=clash+royale&sprefix=clas%2Caps%2C288&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aclash+royale). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add an example of your current code so we can try to help you based on what you already implemented. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are no <item> tags in the example page you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Please search and post code in the future, it took me a few seconds to find an appropriate set of answers for this question.

Sources:

- [Jsoup select and iterate all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036332/jsoup-select-and-iterate-all-elements)
- http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

  ```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get(); 
  Elements elements = doc.body().select("item");

  for (Element element : elements) {
      System.out.println(element.ownText());
  }
  ```

Comment: But how can i iterate the amazon product result  tag name in the html page?

Answer (score 0):

> I (...) need to iterate through item tags in the document, but I cannot find the tag.

There's no tag `item`. Instead it's a `div` element with `s-item-container` class.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Document doc = Jsoup //
                .connect("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_4?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=clash+royale&sprefix=clas%2Caps%2C288&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aclash+royale") //
                .get();

for (Element item : doc.select("div.s-item-container")) {
     System.out.println("-----");
     System.out.println("Title: " + item.select("a.s-access-detail-page").attr("title"));
     System.out.println("Customer Reviews Count: " + item.select("a[href$=#customerReviews]").text());

     // Extract other data...
}
```

#### OUTPUT (stripped)

```
-----
Title: 
Customer Reviews Count: 
-----
Title: Impact ryale
Customer Reviews Count: 1
-----
Title: Castle Clash: Age of Legends
Customer Reviews Count: 6,001
-----
Title: Geometry Dash Meltdown
Customer Reviews Count: 2,924
(...)
```